# How to edit files in Root with Gedit

Tags: 12.04, permissions, root, gedit

I need to edit a file for a lab, but I do not have permission as it is only to root and when I go through root, I get this

```
    ** (gedit:3530): WARNING **: The connection is closed

    (gedit:3530): EggSMClient-WARNING **: Failed to connect to the session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported


 ** (gedit:3530): WARNING **: Could not connect to session bus
[03/30/2017 16:30] root@ubuntu:/home/seed# ^C
[03/30/2017 16:31] root@ubuntu:/home/seed# gksudo gedit/etc/bind/named.config.options

 ** (gksudo:3539): WARNING **: The connection is closed

(gksudo:3539): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running


(gksudo:3539): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running


(gksudo:3539): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running


(gksudo:3539): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running


(gksudo:3539): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_free: assertion `value != NULL' failed

** (gedit:3542): WARNING **: The connection is closed

(gedit:3542): EggSMClient-WARNING **: Failed to connect to the session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported


** (gedit:3542): WARNING **: Could not connect to session bus
```

This is the command I used once I got Root access

```
[03/30/2017 16:32] root@ubuntu:/home/seed# gksudo gedit /etc/bind/named.config.options
```

I need to add a dump file to the options. How do I gain access?

Comment: If you are already logged in as root (#), then you don't need gksudo; all you need do is gedit. On the other hand, I suggest that you exit out of root and do gksudo.

Comment: Are you logged in locally or over ssh?

Answer (score 0):

Use *CTRL + ALT + F1* to get to the tty

log in with your user and ...

```
sudo su
startx
```

Launch Gedit

When you are finished log out

```
exit
exit
```

and use *CTRL + ALT + F7*